# Вывод элементов списка по правилу: текущий элемент, предыдущий элемент

Tags: списки, prolog

Prolog. Необходимо вывести список вот по такому правило

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
1,2
2,3
3,4,
4,5
```

вроде как-то нужно сохранять голову на каждому шагу, но в итоге получаю вот такой косяк

```
пусто, 1
1,2
2,3
3,4 
4,5
```

Comment: на каждой итерации выводить: текущий элемент + предыдущий элемент, начиная с первого
1,2
2,3

Comment: пролог видите ли нынче не так популярен:-) А зря.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 Сколько у него диалектов-то? И который изучать?

Comment: @alexlz, лично я рекомендовал бы SWI-Prolog - свободная и активно развивающаяся реализация.

Comment: Visual Prolog напичкан всякими фишечками, плюшечками, только не бесплатен в отличии SWI-Prolog

Comment: @insolor сложно всё это. Когда мне (в учебных целях) потребовался язык логического программирования, я использовал Curry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_%28programming_language%29

Кстати, мне с тех времён вспоминается статья (гугл подсказал): http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~antoy/homepage/publications/narrowing/paper.pdf

Comment: Сложно только в самом начале. Дальше программы писать довольно легко.

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
domains
integer_list = integer*

predicates
wr_list(integer_list)

clauses
wr_list([]).

wr_list([H|[Y|T]]):-write(H),write(','),write(Y),write(' '),wr_list([Y|T]).
```